NixOS is a VM periodically loses connectivity. How to debug?
According to ip addr everything is still up, but any attempts to ping other hosts including the gateway fail.
Observed this issue under UTM on M1 Mac and under Hyper-V on Windows AMD64. Doesn't apply to all my NixOS on VM installations though.
The only suspect I have is services.nebula.networks that enables Nebula, cause between the 3 of my NixOS VMs 2 with it enabled experience this issue, while the other one does not. There's literally no other network related configuration at all except opening some firewall ports:
networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 443 3001 ];
networking.firewall.allowedUDPPorts = [ 443 ];

Even if Nebula is the cause, why would it affect regular LAN connectivity?
